# RabbitMQ Library Error:

Tags: rabbitmq

I am getting a error when i run this rabbitmqserver.php file. 
i googled and i couldn't find the answer. 
I have all the libraries installed and i added the extension=amqp.so in the php5/cli file. 
the error reads as:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Failed to start request processor: exception 'AMQPConnectionException' with message 'Library error: a socket error occurred - Potential login failure.' in /home/ozzy/git/rabbitmqphp_example/rabbitMQLib.inc:110
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/ozzy/git/rabbitmqphp_example/rabbitMQLib.inc(110): AMQPConnection->connect()
#1 /home/ozzy/git/rabbitmqphp_example/testRabbitMQServer.php(35): rabbitMQServer->process_requests('requestProcesso...')
#2 {main} in /home/ozzy/git/rabbitmqphp_example/rabbitMQLib.inc on line 132
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to localhost:15672 and add a user called test along with a password. then i went inside Virtual host and added a virtual host and it worked.